# Table in loop not displaying data correctly

Tags: c

I have a small program that converts a user input from Fahrenheit to Celsius. Then after that it display Fahrenheit from 1 too 100 with their respective Celsius counterpart. But when run, it outputs this.

> 20 Fahrenheit = -15 Celcius      25 Fahrenheit = -15 Celcius     30
>   Fahrenheit = -15 Celcius
>   35 Fahrenheit = -15 Celcius      40 Fahrenheit = -15 Celcius     45
>   Fahrenheit = -15 Celcius
>   50 Fahrenheit = -15 Celcius
>   6 Fahrenheit = -14 Celcius     12 Fahrenheit = -14 Celcius     18
>   Fahrenheit = -14 Celcius
>   24 Fahrenheit = -14 Celcius      30 Fahrenheit = -14 Celcius     36
>   Fahrenheit = -14 Celcius
>   42 Fahrenheit = -14 Celcius      48 Fahrenheit = -14 Celcius     54
>   Fahrenheit = -14 Celcius
>   60 Fahrenheit = -14 Celcius
>   7 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius     14 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius     21
>   Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius
>   28 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius      35 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius     42
>   Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius
>   49 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius      56 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius     63
>   Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius
>   70 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius
>   8 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius     16 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius     24
>   Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius
>   32 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius      40 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius     48
>   Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius
>   56 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius      64 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius     72
>   Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius
>   80 Fahrenheit = -13 Celcius
>   9 Fahrenheit = -12 Celcius     18 Fahrenheit = -12 Celcius     27
>   Fahrenheit = -12 Celcius
>   36 Fahrenheit = -12 Celcius      45 Fahrenheit = -12 Celcius     54
>   Fahrenheit = -12 Celcius

here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Clear the screen
    system("clear");

    float celsius, fahrenheit;
    printf("Please enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: \n");
    scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);

    //Converts the temperature from fahrenheit to celsius
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;

    printf("%.2f Fahrenheit = %.2f Celsius \n", fahrenheit, celsius);
    printf ("-------------------------------- \n");

    int i,j;
    int num;
    float c;

    //Loop to create table
    for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        num = i;
        for(j=1; j<=10; j++)
        {
            c = (i*j-32) * 5 / 9;
            printf("%3d Fahrenheit = %f Celcius \t",(i*j), c);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The table isnt going from 1 to 100 correctly and the Celsius value displayed in the table is wrong

Comment: You are printing `(num*j)` (which is `i*j`) but you aren't using that value for the conversion to deg C. You are using `i`, the outer loop counter.

Comment: do you see how you have `celsius` and `fahrenheit` declared as floats at the top but `c` is declared as an `int` but trying to store a value of a fraction `(i-32) * 5/9`? That's an issue.  Also, `(i-32)` should really be `(i*j-32)`Also there is no need for num=i you can simply remove `num` altogether and use `(i*j)` in your printf.

Comment: Also why do you need 2 counters 1 to 10 and 1 to 10 ? Why not a simple 1 to 100 counter?

Comment: I have update the code, table still is a mess, wondering how I can format it better

Comment: Please do not modify the code in the question.  It makes any prior comments nonsensical.  Rather add an `EDIT` section that has the new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a summary of issues and fixes:

## Making sure you use the correct types for floats/doubles

Suggest that you make a function:

```
double f2c(double f) {
     return (f - 32.0) * 5/9;
}

int main() {
      printf("%g°F = %g°C\n", 100.0, f2c(100.0));
}
```

## Counting from 0 to 99

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   }

## pretty printing 0-99 every with new line for 10s

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         print("%3d%1c", i, (1+i) % 10? ' ' : '\n');
   }

## Putting it all together

```
#include <stdio.h>

double f2c(double f) {
     return (f - 32) * 5/9;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 213; i++) {
        printf("%3d°F => %3.0f°C%s", i, f2c(i), (1+i) % 10? " | " : "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use float? Better to use double, and better to explicitly use double primitives:`return (f - 32.0) * 5./9.;`